# how to install Strongloop api in node.js and can use loopback

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

When Installing strongloop api in node.js with npm install -g strongloop  command it gives error and slc file is not genrated and after that i can not use slc loopback    command.

Is there any solution for this errors and can use this strongloop.

```
errors:
29646 error Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Daffolap-203\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-pm\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\strong-cluster-control\node_modules\rc\README.md'
29647 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
29647 error including the npm and node versions, at:
29647 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
29648 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
29649 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "strongloop"
29650 error cwd D:\piyush\loopback
29651 error node -v v0.10.31
29652 error npm -v 1.4.23
29653 error path C:\Users\Daffolap-203\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-pm\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\strong-cluster-control\node_modules\rc\README.md
29654 error code ENOENT
29655 error errno 34
29656 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Piyush,

If you want to use LoopBack but run into installation errors please use the following workaround:

```
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-loopback
```

Then,  instead of `slc loopback`, use `yo loopback` instead, including for all the generators, for example `yo loopback:model`.  For more information on Yeoman, see http://yeoman.io/.

hth

Answer (score 0):

What is your node and npm version

```
$    node -v
$    npm -v
```

Can you check to see if you have the right privs to install  globally. You could try a simple module to make sure like

```
$    npm install -g semver 
$    semver -h
```

Also the errors above are incomplete and not really helpful, if you could provide full console logs on pastebin/gist or send us an email callback[at]strongloop.com that would be great. thanks

Comment: My node version V0.10.31 an npm 1.4.23

Comment: Those versions should work fine. Did you try the next step or send us the log.